# How to Connect To My Server Application which is behind a Firewall/NAT?

Tags: networking, tcp, network-programming, firewall

I'm doing a project which involves making a server which uses TCP to connect to its clients. In real-life conditions, it could be behind a firewall/nat/proxy.

So, how would I establish a connection?

**I looked into TCP Hole Punching. Is that the way?**

**Are there any existing libraries so that I don't have to code from scratch?**

Answer (score 0):

If you only have one server and N clientes connected to that server using TCP, the usual way is to map it in the Firewall/Nat. So everything that hits a certain tcp port from outside it's redirected to your server.

Hole Punching is used when you have multiple clients that need to be reached from outside their LAN, example VoIP applications (Skype), that way there's no need that every user of the application have to configure his Firewall/NAT.

Comment: I'm making a Gnutella network. So multiple clients and servers exist. I did some research myself and found this: http://nutss.gforge.cis.cornell.edu//stunt.php

Does this suit my need?

Comment: Yes STUNT is a popular protocol for Hole Punching, you need to set up a STUNT server or use a STUNT service provider.